# VBA UDF to return cell numberformat

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to make a UDF in Excel, that returns the numberformat of a cell (eg : Number, Date, Percentage etc...)

I tried this but it returns nothing (empty)

```
Function Getnumfo(rng As Range) As String
    Application.Volatile
    Dim str As String
    rng.NumberFormat = str
    Getnumfo = str
End Function
```

thanks for the help !

Comment: `str = rng.NumberFormat`, instead of `rng.NumberFormat = str`?

Comment: This will throw an error btw if you pass it a range of cells that don't all have the same number format.

Answer (score 0):

thanks bigben ! this worked

```
Function Getnumfo(rng As Range) As String
    Application.Volatile
    Dim str As String
    str =rng.NumberFormat
    Getnumfo = str
End Function
```